# NDSolve not finding the right solution for a mass hanging of a thread

Tags: differential-equations, simulation, modeling

My `NDSolve` isn't predicting the right trajectory for one particular case of a problem.

### System

Consider a mass vertically hanging by an almost inelastic thread. The thread's force acts acting to the potential

```
springV[x_] := If[x > l, k (x - l)^2/2, If[x < -l, k (-x - l)^2/2, 0]]
```

where `x` is the mass' position. Basically if the mass stretches the string beyond a length `l`, the string pulls back like a Hook spring$^1$ while if it goes limp, it exerts no force at all.

Let's say the string has an unstretched length`l`.  When the mass starts to fall under gravity from initial positions greater than or less than `l`, `NDSolve`, gives the right trajectory. However for what is IMO the simplest case $-$ starting from rest at `l`,  `NDSolve` fails. The solution it produces is one of *pure* free fall instead of the expected oscillations about equilibrium.

### Code

```
(*aliases*)
echo = Echo;
cls = ClearAll;
first = First;
flatAll[x___] := Flatten[x, Infinity];

(*package - using lagrangian*)
Needs@"VariationalMethods`";

Module[
 {springV, eqns, initConds, x0, v0, x, v, L},
 
 (*the spring potential*)
 springV[x_] := 
  If[x > l, k (x - l)^2/2, If[x < -l, k (-x - l)^2/2, 0]];
  
 (*the lagrangian - T-V; V=0 @x1=0 +ve down*)
 L = m1 x1'[t]^2/2 - springV[x1[t]] + m1 g x1[t];
 
 (*the eqn to solve ma=mg-T*)
 eqns = EulerEquations[L, {x1[t]}, t];
 (*inital conditions*)
 initConds = {x1[0] == x10, x1'[0] == v10};
 (*combine them*)
 eqns = flatAll@{eqns, initConds} // echo;
    (*
    sim params: everything is one except 
    gravity(=9.8)  
    inital velocity(=0)
    k=10^4
*)
 vals = {m1 -> 1, k -> 10^4, l -> 1, x10 -> 1., v10 -> 0, g -> 9.8};
 sol = NDSolve[eqns /. vals // echo, {x1[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];
 xsol = {x1[t]} /. first@sol
 ]
```

### Getting $\ldots$

The yielded solution is a parabola instead of the expected$^2$ oscillations about some $x_0^{[3]}$

[image: plots showing a parabola over a 400x cosine]

Unmagnified, the solution is `1.00098 - 0.00098 Cos[100. t]`$^4$ (ignore the plotting artifact around the origin in the magnified expected solution)

Even though in the above I have taken an almost inelastic string by taking a large $k$ relative to $m g$, the same problem exists even with `k=1`.

### Questions

1. Why is `NDSolve` not giving the right answer and how to correct it?

I have (blindly) tried basic `NDSolve` variants under "Possible Issues" from docs. to no avail.

---

### Test cases (in case your results differ)

In case you have come up with your own code, do test to see it matches the behavior at other `x10` values

[image]

---

**Footer**

$^1$ For a hook spring the restorative force is $\propto$ $-$extension$^1$ i.e. its linear.

$^2$using `DSolve[{m1 x''[t] == m1 g - k (x[t] - l), x[0] == x10,  x'[0] == v10} /. vals, x[t], t]`

$^3$$x_0=l+mg/k=1.00098$ for the given sim

$^4$ i.e. it oscillates about the equilibrium position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**final modification**

potential `springV[x]` isn't unique at `x==1`. `NDSolve` has problems to solve with starting value `x1[0]==1`.

Try option `Method -> {Automatic, "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`

```
sol = NDSolve[eqns /. vals // echo,{x1[t]}, {t, 0, 100} , 
Method -> {Automatic,"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];
xsol = {x1[t]} /. first@sol]   
Plot[xsol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange ->{-1.1, 1.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: what was the issue with my code? I rechecked it .. seems to be working (wrongly) on my machine...btw running Mathematica 12.2....were the err codes any help?

Comment: strange.. ran your code ditto....its giving a parabola instead....yep re ran still parabola

Comment: btw the curve you show isn't the expected answer for the given params...the mass should stay $\approx 1$

Comment: Some strange things happened. After correcting the potential the result is as expected. See my modified answer.

Comment: at least i am getting what you are getting...but the solution you got is still wrong (do carefully observe the sol I have provided)....I'll add some test cases

Comment: Sorry, it's not my task to check your code. I provided a working code, not more. It's up to you to check why it differs from your expectation!

Comment: By the way your expected solution doesn't fullfill the initial conditions `x1[0]==1,x1'[0]==0`

Comment: well I checked yours...the lagrangian you used is wrong -- its a plus in the $mgx$ term....with that correction your code too gives a parabola so its not working after all .......since you are modelling the same system as in my question (if not, the answer isn't on point) my *expectation* of the same solution isn't unjustified.

Comment: *By the way your expected solution doesn't fullfill the initial conditions*  oh it does ...its a plotting artifact...good catch! providing better details as we speak

Comment: btw did u change anything other than inbuilt `EulerEquations` $\to$ explicit `D`...i am guessing `if`$\to$ `Which` doesn't matter? oh yeah `NDSolve`$\to$`NDSolveValue`

Comment: relax, take a deep breath.....and plz read the question carefully. (1) I just realized that you have adopted a different convention than me (I am using +ve down) and thats fine as long as you had stayed consistent - with your signs the $mgx$ term in lagrangian would indeed be negative *but so would* the *x10* you use ..with that correction your results (and problems) match mine.  (2.) The question is about $l=1$ not before not after, I am getting correct results there anyways. When you start from equilibrium i.e. zero force you shouldn't get any oscillations at all!$\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$ I see you added a non-zero velocity term while starting from equilib. why?? the question is about starting from rest from $l=1$

Comment: $l=-1$ in your convention